# For Vars, what does static and dynamic mean?

Tags: clojure

From the clojure documentation on vars at https://clojure.org/reference/vars

> By default Vars are static, but Vars can be marked as dynamic

What do static and dynamic mean?

I was able to redefine a var multiple times even though it was not explicitly marked as dynamic.

Comment: Also you can use dynamic vars for configurations and stuff like that.

Answer (score 0):

Vars need to be explicitly marked as `^:dynamic` in order for them to be dynamically rebindable:

```
=> (def ^:dynamic x 1)
=> (def ^:dynamic y 1)
=> (+ x y)
=> 2
```

;; Within the scope of the `binding`, `x` = 2 and `y` = 3

```
=> (binding [x 2 y 3]
         (+ x y))
=> 5
```